# RewriteRule is not creating a GET Argument for API

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule productApi/(.*)$ productApi.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I request with myserver/productAPI/cloths
It loads the productAPI.php but the $_REQUEST is empty, which should have been an array ['category' => 'cloths']

I have set up trace8 logs for mod rewrite and I get the following log

```
add path info postfix: D:/myshop/productApi.php -> D:/myshop/productApi.php/cloths
strip per-dir prefix: D:/myshop/productApi.php/cloths -> productApi.php/cloths
applying pattern 'productApi/(.*)$' to uri 'productApi.php/cloths'
pass through D:/myshop/productApi.php
add path info postfix: D:/myshop/productApi.php -> D:/myshop/productApi.php/cloths
strip per-dir prefix: D:/myshop/productApi.php/cloths -> productApi.php/cloths
applying pattern 'productApi/(.*)$' to uri 'productApi.php/cloths'
pass through D:/myshop/productApi.php
strip per-dir prefix: D:/myshop/cloths -> cloths
applying pattern 'productApi/(.*)$' to uri 'cloths'
pass through D:/myshop/cloths
```

I have read and changed many different things but it did not help me.
I don't know what is the issue but something is wrong with how it handles the Rewrite Rule.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by option `MultiViews`.

Turn it off by placing this line at the top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.